# How to find a list of Elemenets/Attributes from a specific Element in XML?

Tags: c#, xml, winforms, linq-to-xml

How can I query an xml document to return a list of sub-elements/attributes of a specific element.

```
var entry = from item in doc.Descendants("GROUP")
                        where (string)item.Attribute("meetsMark") == "1"
                        select new
                        {                                
                            code = (string)item.Attribute("code"),                               
                        };
```

The above returns only the entries that belong to the element GROUP, where the meetsMark attribute is "1". For each of those elements that it returns the code for I need to also get a list of the 'sum' and 'number' for every SUMMARY attribute it contains.
Example: I need to have the query return:

code = SECONDARY

sum = SUM1

number = 1

sum = SUM3

number = 3

sum = SUM4

number = 4

code =THIRD

sum = SUM10

number = 1

sum = SUM30

number = 3

sum = SUM40

number = 4

Below is the xml structure.

> ```
> <GROUP
>     id="GRP2"
>     code="MAIN"             
>     meetsMark="0"
>
>     <GROUP
>         id="GRP3"               
>         code="SECONDARY"    
>         meetsMark="1"
>
>             <ITEMS>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM6"                           
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM1"
>                         number="1"                                                      
>
>                     </SUMMARY>
>                 </ITEM>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM14"                          
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM3"
>                         number="3"                                                      
>
>                     </SUMMARY>                          
>                 </ITEM>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM15"                          
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM4"
>                         number="4"                          
>
>                     </SUMMARY>                          
>                 </ITEM>                     
>             </ITEMS>                    
>         </GROUP>
>         <GROUP
>         id="GRP4"               
>         code="THIRD"    
>         meetsMark="1"
>
>             <ITEMS>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM95"                          
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM10"
>                         number="1"                                                      
>
>                     </SUMMARY>
>                 </ITEM>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM96"                          
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM30"
>                         number="3"                                                      
>
>                     </SUMMARY>                          
>                 </ITEM>
>                 <ITEM
>                     id="ITM97"                          
>
>                     <SUMMARY
>                         sum="SUM40"
>                         number="4"                          
>
>                     </SUMMARY>                          
>                 </ITEM>                     
>             </ITEMS>                    
>         </GROUP>
> </GROUP>
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be something like this ... (line feeds omitted for clarity)

```
var groups = from group in doc.Descendants("GROUP")
            where (string)group.Attribute("meetsMark") == "1"
            select group

var subgroups = from subgroup in groups.Descendants("GROUP")
           where subgroup.Attribute("code").Value == "SECONDARY"
           select subgroup;

foreach( var subgroup in subgroups )
{
   System.Console.WriteFormat( "code = {0}", subgroup.Attribute("code").Value );

   var sums = from summary in subgroup.Descendants("SUMMARY")

   foreach( var sum in sums )
   {
       System.Console.WriteFormat( "sum = {0}", subgroup.Attribute("sum").Value );
       System.Console.WriteFormat( "number = {0}", subgroup.Attribute("number").Value );
   }
}
```

Comment: I tried using your answer, but it is throwing a fit over 'var groups = from group...'. It says 'Identifier Expected', which I'm not entirely clear as to the issue. 'group' seems to be a keyword, so I'm not sure if it's intentional, or if it is supposed to use a variable name like my original example?